# Parsing ASCII in raw memory in C

Tags: c, libraries

My goal is to parse potentially garbled ASCII data containing text and numbers. So far I've been doing fine with getting a pointer to numbers within the text with `strcmp` and hard-coded pointer arithmetic and then converting them with `strtol`, but I feel there must be a better way.

Is there a function with the effect of `scanf` which takes a pointer to memory instead of input stream?

Comment: You mean [`sscanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/sscanf)?

Comment: Are you looking for sscanf ?

Comment: @Kninnug Yes, that's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll be wanting [`sscanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf). Note that it does expect a null-terminated string.